# os.StartProcess() not allowing for sudo commands in golang

Tags: go, exec, system-calls, root, sudo

I am trying to start a new process from within a rootless golang program, give that process root privileges, and execute a command using sudo. However, I am getting the following output:

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 65534, should be 0
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 65534, should be 0
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
exit status 1
```

Which I am assuming means I need to chown some files temporarily in order to have sudo access. Is this process possible? here is my StartProcess code currently

```
cred := &syscall.Credential{0, 0, []uint32{}, false}
sys := &syscall.SysProcAttr{Credential: cred, Noctty: false}
attr := os.ProcAttr{Env: os.Environ(), Files: []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}, Sys: sys}
proc, err := os.StartProcess("/bin/sudo", []string{"/bin/podman", "image", "load", "--input=" + scpOpts.Save.Output}, &attr)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

state, err := proc.Wait()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

fmt.Println(state.String())
```

Comment: Does the command you're trying to run work outside of Go?

Answer (score 0):

Check first the ownership on your `/etc` folder: setting it back to root (as in here) should help.

You had a similar [podman issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/7816#issuecomment-701149465) which illustrates the importance of user ownership.

The [OP cbd123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9592657/cbd123) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474099/os-startprocess-not-allowing-for-sudo-commands-in-golang/69476131?noredirect=1#comment122860899_69476131):

> My issue was that I was not gid or uid mapping properly.
>
> I got it to work except for hte fact that `syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER` has some issues where it triggers an invalid argument error due to the `max_user_namespace` file.

Comment: I am thinking the issue is with the UID/GID the process is starting with. my /etc folder is appropriately owned by root.

Comment: @cbd123 I agree. Could you try `proc, err := os.StartProcess("/bin/sudo", []string{"id", "-a")` ? (to check which is used in your process) Also `proc, err := os.StartProcess("id", []string{"-a")`

Comment: my issue was that I was not gid or uid mapping properly. I got it to work execpt fo rhte fact that `syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER` has some issued where it triggers an invalid argument error due to the max_user_namespace file...

Comment: @cbd123 OK, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: related issue if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509844/syscall-clone-newuser-causing-invalid-argument-error